Fixing DOMException: HTMLMediaElement Already Connected to a Different MediaElementSourceNode in JavaScript Audio Player
The issue arises when clicking the nextBtn and prevBtn in JavaScript audio player. When navigating through different audio tracks using the next or previous buttons, when the arrIndexCount reaches 0, the animation does seem to appear anymore.As for the prevBtn, the animation does not appear as well. It leads to a DOMException: "Failed to execute 'createMediaElementSource' on 'AudioContext': HTMLMediaElement already connected previously to a different MediaElementSourceNode." The error occurs because a media element can only be associated with one MediaElementSourceNode at a time, and previous connections were not properly disconnected before creating new ones.
I have also tried to disconnect it before calling the createAudioVisualiser() method; However, there were no results. Please help.
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Music Player</title>
    <style>
        *{
            margin:0%;
            padding: 0%;
            background-color: black;
            box-sizing:border-box;
        }
        .container{
            height:40pc ;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            border: 2px solid red;
        }

        #innerContainer{
            display: flex;
            align-self: center;
            /* align-content: center; */
            border: 2px solid rgb(237, 237, 247);
            box-shadow: -6px 2px 2px rgb(142, 142, 142);
            height: 600px;
            width:530px;
            justify-content: center;
            animation-name: glowAni;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-duration: 2000ms;
            animation-direction: alternate;
            /* animation-; */
            
            
        }
        
        @keyframes glowAni {
            
            from{
                box-shadow: -6px 2px 2px rgb(142, 142, 142);
                
            }
            to{
                box-shadow: -8px 12px 10px 3px silver
            }
        }





        .Btn{
            display: block;
            border-radius: 37px;
            height: 49px;
            top: 28em;
            position: relative;
            margin-right: 12px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

 

        .BtnImg{
            height: 46px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        #choose{

            display: block;
            margin: auto;
            position: relative;
            top: 72px;
            left: 245px;
            border-radius:20px;
            height: 30px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: cover; 
            cursor: pointer;  
        }

        #slider{
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
            position: relative;
            top: 36em;
            width: 30em;
            
        }

        #musicName{
        color: white;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        top: 470px;
        }
    
        
        #canvas1{
            border:2px solid greenyellow;
            height: 250px;
            width: 516px;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10em;
            left: 0; 
            right: 0; 
            margin-left: auto; 
            margin-right: auto; 
            filter: blur(1.23px) contrast(3.5);
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- <header></header> -->
    <div class="container">

        <canvas id="canvas1">

        </canvas>

        <img id="choose" src="/Projects/Music Player/IMG/add.png" alt="" >
        
        <div id="musicName">Nothing Playing</div>
        <input type="range" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="300">

        <div id="innerContainer">
            <button class="Btn" id="prevBtn">
                <img  class="BtnImg" src="/Projects/Music Player/IMG/back-button.png" alt="" >
            </button>

            <button class="Btn" id="playBtn">
                <img id="playImg" class="BtnImg" src="/Projects/Music Player/IMG/play.png" alt="" >
            </button>

            <button class="Btn" id="nextBtn">
                <img class="BtnImg test" src="/Projects/Music Player/IMG/next-button.png" alt="" >
            </button>
            <br>
            
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        let musicPathArr = [];
        var nameArr = [];
        
        var arrIndexCount = 0;
        let c = 0;
        
        let chooserBtn = document.getElementById('choose');
        let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
        let audio;
        
        canvas.width = innerWidth;
        canvas.height = innerHeight;
        chooserBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            
            let chooser = document.createElement('input');
            chooser.setAttribute('type', 'file');
            chooser.click();


            chooser.addEventListener('change', (e)=>{
                const files = e.target.files
                const fileName = e.target.files[0];
                if(fileName){
                
                    nameArr.push(fileName.name);
                    // console.log(nameArr);
                }
                for(let i=0; i<files.length; i++){
                    const file = files[i];
                    const reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = () =>{
                        var base64Aud = reader.result;
                        audio = new Audio(base64Aud);
                        // console.log(base64Aud);
                        musicPathArr.push(audio);
                        
                        musicPathArr.forEach(aud =>{
                            aud.addEventListener('timeupdate', ()=>{
                    
                                let audDuration  = aud.duration;
                                let sliderVal  = (aud.currentTime *slider.max)/audDuration;
                                slider.value = sliderVal;
                            });
                
                        })
                        // createAudioVisualiser(audio);
 
                        
                    }    
                    
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    
                } 
            });
            
            
        });
        
        
        
        
        
        let displayMusicName = () =>{
            console.log(nameArr[arrIndexCount]);
            musicNameDiv.innerHTML = nameArr[arrIndexCount];
        };


        
        console.log(nameArr);
        
        let cond = true;
        const audioContext = new AudioContext();
        let playBtn = document.getElementById('playBtn');
        let nextBtn = document.getElementById('nextBtn');
        let prevBtn = document.getElementById('prevBtn');
        let slider = document.getElementById('slider');
        let musicNameDiv = document.getElementById('musicName'); 
        
        
        // let aud1 = new Audio("/Projects/Music Player/MP3/song1.mp3");
        // let aud2 = new Audio("/Projects/Music Player/MP3/song2.mp3");
        
        
        
        
        nextBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            musicPathArr[arrIndexCount].pause();
            musicPathArr[arrIndexCount].currentTime = 0;
            arrIndexCount++; // Increment first
            if(arrIndexCount >= musicPathArr.length){ // Check if it's equal to or greater than the length
                arrIndexCount = 0; // Reset to 0 to loop back to the first element
                // createAudioVisualiser(musicPathArr[arrIndexCount]);
            }
            displayMusicName();
            // musicNameDiv.innerHTML = filename;
            audio = musicPathArr[arrIndexCount]; // Update the audio variable
            displayMusicName();
            audio.play(); 
            createAudioVisualiser(audio);
        });
        
        prevBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            try{
                
                musicPathArr[arrIndexCount].pause();
                musicPathArr[arrIndexCount].currentTime = 0;
                if(arrIndexCount<0){
                    
                    arrIndexCount--;
                    // musicNameDiv.innerHTML = filename;
                }
                else{
                    arrIndexCount=0;
                    // createAudioVisualiser(musicPathArr[arrIndexCount]);
                }
                audio = musicPathArr[arrIndexCount]; // Update the audio variable
                displayMusicName();
                audio.play();
                createAudioVisualiser(audio);
            }
            catch(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            
            
        });
        
        
        let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        // const barWidth = 15;
        
        playBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            audioContext.resume().then(()=>{

            });
            if(cond==true){
                
                document.getElementById('playImg').src = "/Projects/Music Player/IMG/pause-button.png";
                musicPathArr[arrIndexCount].play();
                
                cond = false;
                console.log("Play ", arrIndexCount);
                
                displayMusicName();
            }
            else if(cond==false){
                document.getElementById('playImg').src = "/Projects/Music Player/IMG/Play.png";
                musicPathArr[arrIndexCount].pause();
                cond=true;
                console.log("pause");
                
            }
            
            //Audio Visualiser
            createAudioVisualiser(musicPathArr[arrIndexCount]);
                  
            
        });
        
        function drawVisualiser(bufferLength, barWidth, x, dataArray ){
            for( let i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++){
                let barHeight = dataArray[i]*1.5; // Assign the value here
                context.save();
                context.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
                context.rotate(i * Math.PI*4/bufferLength);
                const hue = (i/bufferLength)*360
                context.fillStyle = "hsl(" + hue + ", 80%, 60%)";
                context.fillRect(0, 0, barWidth, barHeight);
                x += barWidth;
                context.restore();
            }
        }
        
        
        function createAudioVisualiser(audio){
            let analyser;
            let audioSource;
            let animationFrameId;
            
            if(audioSource){
                audioSource.disconnect();
            }
     
            if(animationFrameId){
                cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrameId);
            }

            // if(audioContext){
            //     audioContext.close();
            // }


            try{
                audioSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio);
                audioContext.resume().then(()=>{
                    
                });     

                analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
                audioSource.connect(analyser);
                analyser.connect(audioContext.destination)
                analyser.fftSize = 1024;
                const bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
                const dataArr = new Uint8Array(bufferLength)
                let barHeight;
                let x; 
                // const barWidth = (canvas.width/bufferLength)/2;
                const barWidth = 8;
                
                
                function animate(){
                    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                    x = 0;
                    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArr);
                    drawVisualiser(bufferLength, barWidth, x, dataArr);
                    animationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                }
                animate();
            }
            catch(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
        
        slider.addEventListener('input', ()=>{
            let audDuration  = musicPathArr[arrIndexCount].duration;
            let sliderVal  = slider.value;
            let audStreamCurrentTime  = (sliderVal/slider.max)*audDuration; 
            musicPathArr[arrIndexCount].currentTime  = audStreamCurrentTime; 
        });
        



        
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>








I'd recommend that you add audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio) where you define and assign audio = new Audio(base64Aud);. Then store both the Audio instance and the MediaElementAudioSourceNode as an object in the musicPathArr array. This way you don't have to create new MediaElementAudioSourceNode instances later on.
